# Why does my HexToInt function fail in Delphi 64bit when it works in 32bit?

Tags: delphi, 32bit-64bit

HexToInt in Delphi 64bit

I have a HexToInt function that works on binary data in Delphi 32bit but fails with negative values in Delphi 64bit:

```
function HexToInt(MSC, LSC: ANSIChar): Smallint;
begin
result := ord(MSC);
result := (result shl 8) or ord(LSC);
end;
```

For example, with the binary string **ý'** (chr(253) & chr(39)) this function returns -729 however trying the same function in 64bit gives a range error.
I tried using Integer and LongInt as the return value which does give *a* value (64807), but not the right one.

- I realise now that the correct result = 65536 minus this result so I can do an ugly integer math fix in the function but it would be much nicer - and faster - to do it properly!

Comment: Perhaps you should edit and add to your question the code that calls this `HexToInt()` function, iow a **complete** [mre] that also shows the error when it fails.

Comment: By the way, naming a function for `HexToInt()` when you pass a string `ý'` to it, is nonsense, as the character set that can represent hex is limited to '0'..'9', 'A'..'F'. Also, the string `ý'` is not at all binary! A binary string consists of characters '0' and '1' only.

Comment: I can't work out what this function is meant to do. It doesn't do anything related to hex. You seem to be working with byte data. But trying to do so with text encodings, utf16 and ANSI conversions thrown into the mix. Are you confused between binary data, arrays of bytes, and hex data, base 16 text representation where two characters represent a single byte?

Comment: Is it possible that your 32 bit delphi is a pre Unicode version? Like 6 or 7 or 2007?

Comment: I'm voting to close as not reproducible, because the reported behaviour is not reproducible. Both 32 and 64 bit produce range check errors. It's also really important to stress that this code has nothing at all to do with hex.

Comment: Tom, Thanks for the comments. I agree the name is really bad, it is inherited code from about 2002. It is taking 2 byte signed integers streamed from a serial port so this is how they 'appear' in the comms component output.

Comment: David, the code is from Delphi5 I think but still works fine in 32bit Delphi11, just not 64bit.

Comment: No. Its a range check error in Delphi 11 in both 32 and 64 bit. Go back and check your compiler settings. You probably don't have range checking enabled in your 32 bit target.

Comment: But you need to stop using AnsiChar, you need to use Byte. Personally I'd probably just copy the two bytes directly into the two bytes of the smallint using point arithmetic rather than bitwise operations. And it's really confusing to use the word Hex when there is no hex here. It's just going to confuse you.

Comment: Also 65536 - -729 does not equal 64807. It actually is outside the range of Word. And the value that you seem to want is 64807 which doesn't fit in signed smallint. All in all there are a lot of problems with your understanding of this small piece of code and I recommend that you step back and take some time to get on top of this.

Comment: The irony here is that your code runs on delphi 5 and returns the same negative value that you think is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`AnsiChar(253)` has its high bit set to 1 (`%11111101`). Casted to a signed integer, that bit gets extended into the higher bits when you convert the value into a multi-byte integer (`%11111111_11111101`), thus making the integer negative.

The byte sequence `$FD $27` (`%11111101 %00100111`) interpreted as an *unsigned* 16-bit integer is 64807, and as a *signed* 16-bit integer is -729.

To get that kind of result when shifting bits around, try masking off extra bits after `Ord()` conversions and before bitshifts eg:

```
function HexToInt(MSC, LSC: AnsiChar): Smallint;
begin
  Result := Ord(MSC) and $FF;
  Result := (Result shl 8) or (Ord(LSC) and $FF);
end;
```

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that it's a range check error in both 32 and 64 bit Delphi